# Automatically adding lines of file to mongoDB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, runtime

I got a local mongoDB instance running and I have an extremly large file (34GB, almost a billion lines) which i would like to add to the database for fast queries.

Current code should be running about 817 days.

Is there any way to do this faster?

```
with open("big_file.txt", "r") as f:
    next_line = next(f).strip()
    lineCount = 980614462
    currentCount = 1

    while next_line:
    

        d = {
            "key": next_line
        }

        collection.insert_one(d)
        print(f"[{currentCount} / {lineCount}] {currentCount / lineCount} %", end="\r")
        currentCount += 1
        next_line = next(f).strip()
```

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/

Comment: See if it runs faster if you don't print every line.

Comment: That doesnt help that much

Comment: What about using a bulk insert? https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html